# AMP Authorization failed Error

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

This is my first example on amp and there is something I failed with amp this page give me a this error line:

click image to see big version

[image: click image to see big version]

what should I do ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="tr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Otel - Tur Detay Sayfaları</title>
    <!-- canonical url buraya gelecek -->

    <!-- #href kısmına standart sayfa url'i gelecek-->
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://anitur.com.tr/otel/otel-detay-normal-version.html">
    <!--/canonical url bitti-->
    <!-- amp için canonical tagi-->
    <!-- #canonical amp versiyonu için amphtml taginin href özniteliğine sayfanın amp versiyonu yazılacak -->
    <link rel="amphtml" href="http://anitur.com.tr/otel/otel-detay-amp-version.html" /> 

    <!--/ amp için canonical tagi-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="//cdn.anitur.com/web/assets/img/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <!-- amp components-->
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script> 
    <script async custom-element="amp-selector" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-selector-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-access" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-access-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script> 
    <script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>

    <!--/ amp components-->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script id="amp-access" type="application/json">
    {
        "authorization": "authorization?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL&ref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&_=RANDOM",
        "pingback": "pingback?rid=READER_ID&ref=DOCUMENT_REFERRER&url=CANONICAL_URL",
        "login": "/samples_templates/hotel/login?rid=READER_ID&url=CANONICAL_URL",
        "authorizationFallbackResponse": {
            "error": true,
            "access": false
        }
    }
</script>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Aurum Moon Resort",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
            "logo.jpg"
        ]
    }
    </script>
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

    <style amp-custom>
    body {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        background: #eceaeb;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: tahoma;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color:#404040;
    }
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    nav#navigation {
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    #navigation li{
        float:left;
        position: relative;
    }
    #navigation li:before{
  
        display:block;

    }
    #navigation li a{
        font-size: 12px;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    #wrapper{
        background: #FFF;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .layout{
        width:90%;
        margin:10px auto;
    }
    .layout:before,
    .layout:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    ul,ol{

        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
  a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color:#404040;
  }
    
    #detail-header{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #detail-header:before,#detail-header:after{
        content:"";
        display:table;
        clear:both;

    }
    .col-left{
        width:70%;
        float:left;
    }
    .col-right{
        width:30%;
        float:right;
    }
    #detail-header h1{
        margin: 0 0 2px 0;
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    #detail-header ul,#detail-header ol{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #detail-header li{
        display: inline-block;
        background: #eceaeb;
        border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 2px 8px;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .location{
        padding: 0;
        margin:0;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #636363;
    }
      
    .list-details ul,
    .list-details ol{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .list-details li,.list-details li a{
        font-size: 12px;
        position: relative;        
        padding-left: 14px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .list-details li:before{
        content: "";
        width: 5px;
        height: 5px;
        color: #000;
        background: #000;
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        top: 6px;
    }

       #stay-input{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        padding:12px;
       }
       .ampstart-btn.caps{
       background-color: #efefef;
        padding: 7px;
        border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
        margin:5px 0;
       }
       .ampstart-input{
        margin-bottom: 5px;
       }
       [name="guests"]{
        width:50%;
        padding: .3em;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
       }
       .ampstart-input:before,
       .ampstart-input:after{
            content:"";
            display:table;
            clear:both;
       }
    .ampstart-input label{
        float:left;
        width:50%;
    }
    .ampstart-input input{
        float:right;
        width:50%;
        padding: .3em;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px #ddd;
    }
      amp-accordion section[expanded] .show-more {
        display: none;
    }
      amp-accordion section:not([expanded]) .show-less {
        display: none;
      }
      amp-accordion section[expanded]{
            padding: 10px 4px;
      }
      amp-accordion section h4 {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 10px;
        background:#f0f0f0;
      }
    amp-accordion{
           padding:10px 0;
    }
      amp-accordion#hidden-header section[expanded] h4 {
        border: none;
      }
         .ampTabContainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .tabButton[selected] {
        outline: none;
        background: #FFF;
        padding:7px;
    }
    
    .tabButton {
        list-style: none;
        flex-grow: 1;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .tabContent {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        order: 1; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding:10px;;
    }
    
    .tabButton[selected]+.tabContent {
        display: block;
    }
    amp-selector [option][selected]{
       outline:1px solid #ccc;
       background:#f0f0f0;
    }

    .itemCustom {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        height: 280px;
        width: 380px;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 140px;
    }
    amp-selector {
      margin:1rem 0;
    }
      .map{
        margin: 10px;
      }
      .map h4{
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      .services{
            margin:10px 0;
      }
      .services h5{
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
      }
      .services p {
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height:18px;
      }
      .price{
        background: #eceaeb;
        border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      .price span{
        color: #8e8e8e;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      .buy{
        color:#FFF;
        background:orange;
        padding:0;
        display:block;
      }
      .price,.buy{
        font-size: 12px;
        padding:3px;
        margin:0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .go-links{
        margin-left: 9px;
      }
      .go-links a{
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 7px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .go-hotel{
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #f0f0f0;
      }
      .go-call{
        background: #012770;
        border:1px solid #012e85;
        color: #FFF;
      }
    .call-number{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
     }
      .call-number h5{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
      }
      .call-number a{
        display: block;
      }

      #carousel-with-preview amp-img {
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    .carousel-preview {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .carousel-preview button {
      height: 40px;
      width: 60px;
      min-width: 60px;
      margin: 4px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .carousel-preview .amp-carousel-slide {
      margin: 4px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .carousel-preview button:active {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
   .checkit h5{
        margin: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
   }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- header-->
     <header class="layout">
          <!-- logo-->
        <div class="logo col-left">
            <amp-img src="img/logo.png" width="60" height="57" alt="Anı Tur"></amp-img>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right call-number">
            <h5>Bilgi ve Rezervasyon</h5>
            <a href="tel:08503000264" class="first-number">0850 300 02 64</a>
            <a href="tel:4440264" class="last-number">444 0 264</a>
        </div>
          <!-- logo-->
      </header>
    <!--/header -->

      
        <!--/navigation-->
    <main id="wrapper" class="layout">
        <!-- detay header-->
        <div id="detail-header">
           <div class="col-left">
                <h1>Aurum Moon Resort</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Ultra Her Şey Dahil</li>
                    <li>Oda Kahvaltı</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="location">Didim,Yeşilkent</p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-right">
                <a href="#" class="buy">SATIN AL</a>
               <p class="price">
                   269.75 TL
                   <span>'den itibaren</span>
               </p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <!--/ detay header-->


        <!-- detay body-->
        <div id="detail-body">

            <!-- slider alanı-->
            <div id="detail-slider">
                <amp-carousel id="carousel-with-carousel-preview" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" type="slides">
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero2_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="resim açıklama"></amp-img>
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero3_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero1_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero2_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero3_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero1_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                  <amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero2_1024x683.jpg" width="400" height="250" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img>
                </amp-carousel>
                <amp-carousel class="carousel-preview" width="auto" height="48" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=0)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero2_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=1)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero3_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=2)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero1_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=0)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero2_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=1)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero3_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=2)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero1_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
                  <button on="tap:carousel-with-carousel-preview.goToSlide(index=0)"><amp-img src="https://ampbyexample.com/img/product_hero2_1024x683.jpg" width="60" height="40" layout="responsive" alt="a sample image"></amp-img></button>
            
                
                </amp-carousel>
            </div>
            <!--/slider alanı-->

            <!-- Fiyat Sorgulama-->
                  <div class="checkit">
                  <h5>Oda fiyatlarını görmek için tarih seç</h5>
                  <form method="GET" class="px3 mb4" action="check-available" action-xhr="check-available" target="_top">
                    <fieldset id="stay-input" class="border-none p0 m0">
                      <div class="ampstart-input relative m0 p0 mb3">
                        <label for="checkin">Check-in:</label>
                        <input name="checkin"
                          id="checkin"
                          type="date"
                          class="block border-none p0 m0"
                          value="2017-08-15">
                      </div>
                      <div class="ampstart-input relative m0 p0 mb3">
                        <label for="checkout">Check-out:</label>
                        <input name="checkout"
                          type="date"
                          class="block border-none p0 m0"
                          value="2017-08-16">
                      </div>
                      <div class="ampstart-input relative m0 p0 mb3 ">
                        <label for="guests">Kişi Sayı:</label>
                        <select name="guests"
                          class="block border-none p0 m0">
                          <option value="1">1</option>
                          <option value="2"
                            selected>2</option>
                          <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="submit" value="Göster" class="ampstart-btn caps">
                    <div submit-success>
                      <template type="amp-mustache">
                        Bulunan Odalar Buraya Gelecek
                      </template>
                    </div>
                    <div submit-error>
                      <template type="amp-mustache">
                        Müsait oda yok
                      </template>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  </div>
            <!--/ Fiyat Sorgulama-->

       <amp-selector role="tablist" layout="container" class="ampTabContainer">
          <div role="tab" class="tabButton" selected option="a">Yaz Sezonu</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">
              
                <!-- Oda Özellikleri -->
            <amp-accordion>
                <section>
                          <h4>Genel Özellikler</h4>
                            <!-- Genel Özellikler -->
                            <div class="list-details">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Ana Restaurant ( Açık )</li>
                                    <li>Çocuk Oyun Alanları *</li>
                                    <li>Laminant Zemin</li>
                                    <li>Açık Havuz</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ Genel Özellikler -->
                </section>
                <section>
                          <h4>Plaj Özellikleri</h4>
                          <!-- Genel Özellikler -->
                            <div class="list-details">
                                <ol>
                                    <li>Ana Restaurant ( Açık )</li>
                                    <li>Çocuk Oyun Alanları *</li>
                                    <li>Laminant Zemin</li>
                                    <li>Açık Havuz</li>
                                </ol>
                            </div>
                            <!--/ Genel Özellikler -->
                          
                </section>
            </amp-accordion>
            <!--/ Oda Özellikleri Bitiş-->

            <!-- Hizmetler -->
                <div class="services">
                    <h5>KONUM</h5>
                    <p>Tesis, Denizyaka Mevkiindedir. Antalya merkeze 60 km, Antalya havaalanına 50 km, Belek, Side ve Manavgat' a 30 km mesafededir. Toplam 1.000.000 m2 alana kurulmuştur.</p>
                </div>


        
            <!--/ Hizmetler -->
          </div>
        
          <div role="tab" class="tabButton" option="b">Kış Sezonu</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tabContent">Kış sezonu </div>
        </amp-selector>
          
            
           <!-- Harita -->
             <div class="map">
                <h4>HARİTA</h4>
                 <amp-iframe 
                  width="600"
                  height="300"
                  layout="responsive"
                  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
                  frameborder="0"
                  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d12047.436573933934!2d29.098413750000002!3d40.984565100000005!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1str!2str!4v1463140023736">
                </amp-iframe>
             </div>
           <!--/ Harita Bitiş-->

        <!--/  Detay footer -->
        </div>
        <!--/ detay body-->


        <!-- Detay footer -->
            <div id="detay-footer">
                <div class="go-links">
                    <a href="#" class="go-hotel">Otele Git</a>
                    <a href="#" class="go-call">Sizi Arayalım</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </main>
    <!-- kapsayıcı -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` such as, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.yoursite.com`

Comment: where should I add this ? and thank you @BlueSuiter

Comment: You are using `GET` method so there is no need of `action-xhr`. What are you using for handling form submission.